# Trino not automatically scan the new load data in source

Tags: hive, minio, trino

I am using Trino to read partition parquet file using following two queries, but one thing I observed is Trino will not automatically scan the partition directories, which means when there are new loaded parquet files in the partition folder, the data will not automatically show up at Trino table that I create, I checked the Hive connector setting for `hive.cache.enabled` and `hive.file-status-cache-tables`, they are all default values, has anyone met this situation before, or any idea why this happens?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS minio.xxx.currency (
currency_code VARCHAR,
currency_name VARCHAR,
firmid VARCHAR,
source VARCHAR,
year VARCHAR,
month VARCHAR,
day VARCHAR,
time VARCHAR,
correlationid VARCHAR
)
with (
external_location = 's3a://xxx/currency/',
partitioned_by = ARRAY['firmid','source','year','month','day','time','correlationid'],
format = 'PARQUET');
```

```
CALL minio.system.sync_partition_metadata
(
schema_name=>'xxx',
table_name=>'currency',
mode=>'FULL',
case_sensitive=>false
);
```

Comment: I have similar issue; when there is a new partition directory, Trino will not query the latest data. Did you find how to solve this question?